# Bootstrap slider width parent (12 breakpoint)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay so I have a slider that's in a normal container (not containter-fluid).
The problem is that the slider isn't the full 100% width (Look at the picture). I've tried adding css width and height 100% but it doesn't work.
I need the slider to be 100% width (12 col-lg-12). 
[image]

You can see the white space. It needs to be filled.

Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> Mobtech </title>

        <!--Ubaci bootstrap css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="css/basic-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- Nas font -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Slider -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12"> 

                        <div id="mojslider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                            <!-- Indikatori (male tacke na slajderu) -->
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#mojslider" data-slider-to="0" class="active"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#mojslider" data-slider-to="1"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#mojslider" data-slider-to="2"> </li>
                            </ol>
                            <!-- Slajd-slike -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                <!--Svaki div je jedan slajd -->
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <img src="Slike/samsung.png" alt="samsungslide" />
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                        <h1> <font face="Roboto Condensed" size="15" color="white"> Samsung Galaxy s7  </font> </h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="Slike/iphone.png" alt="iphoneslide" />
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                        <h1> <font face="Roboto Condensed" size="15" color="white"> iPhone 7 </font> </h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="Slike/lg.png" alt="lglide" />
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                        <h1> <font face="Roboto Condensed" size="15" color="white"> LG V10 </font> </h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Kontrole - next i prev dugme -->
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mojslider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mojslider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
                            </a>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br/>

            <!--Container 1 - Mobtech - uvek sa Vama! -->
            <div class="container"> 
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Kolona na velikom ekranu (lg) prikazuje duzinu jedne kolone, Ekstra small (xs) prikazuje 4 kolone -->
                    <div class="col-lg-12 bg-zelenapozadina"> 
                        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-zelenapozadina">
                            <center> <font face="Roboto Condensed" size="6"> Mobtech - uvek sa Vama ! </font> </center>
                            <p> 
                            <font face="Roboto Condensed" size="4"> 
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, his no postulant liberavisse. At nibh lucilius sed. Omnium latine efficiendi ea vis. Elit facilisis mel et. Eu qui erat tation elaboraret. Ut nec tamquam vocibus urbanitas, euripidis contentiones usu ex, luptatum maiestatis mea cu.

                            Iriure accommodare vim et. Sed alia munere pertinax no. Duo eu sumo possim, nam te omnis offendit, no scaevola oportere his. Ut qui dolor scripserit reprehendunt. Ne sea zril vivendo, duo iudico aliquam laoreet eu, cu nullam essent delectus ius.

                            Pri facer accusam omittam eu, eam id dico prompta recusabo. Vix an suas alia putent, quo utinam deleniti legendos ne. Vis et nibh fugit aliquam. Ex est salutandi interesset, soluta ancillae incorrupte sea ne. Qui id velit dicunt interpretaris, ad option blandit nam. Odio mucius adversarium has at. Duo option intellegebat signiferumque ex, ut oblique detraxit sit.
                            </font>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br/>

            <!-- JavaScript fajl -->
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Kompresovan JavaScript fajl -->
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Bootstrap's container has 15 pixels of padding on each side. Use a class to remove this padding. Easiest and perhaps one of the wisest ways to do this is to add `noPadding` class to the same div your slideshow's `container` is.

After that, you just set up the following CSS:

```
.noPadding { padding: 0 !important; }
```

The reason your other areas of the page seem to be wider than your slider is that the padding does not affect background-color.

Comment: It worked ! I just added style="padding: 0 !important;" to the HTML code, because it's not long. Thank you so much ProDexorite! :-)

Comment: You're welcome! If you run in to the same issue again, I would recommend making it a class, since you can use it anywhere you don't want to have any additional padding. Same goes for elements with margin. :)

Comment: By the way; If you're set this up to your HTML code and you're only using it in removing the container's padding, you can remove the `!important` part, should work without it.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the `.container: padding: 0;` the `<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12"></div>` will be with 30px widther. I sugest you do that:

```
.col-lg12.col-sm-12 {
   padding: 0;
}
```